# Google App Engine - why is User Class user_id different from Googleapis id

Tags: python, google-app-engine

user_id in GAE is different than id in Google APIs

Example - for the same email@gmail.com

**GAE (user_id) = 115540519337309141732**

whereas

**Google API `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`(id) = 135544519337309141732 which happens to be the same id if you go to plus.google.com/id**

So I was wondering if it's possible to get the Google API id in GAE without having to go through OAuth2 because I can't get that to work, but I can get Users Class to work. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any way to map from the one to the other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are correct, the Id space used by App Engine is different to that used by other Google sign in APIs and there's currently no easy way to do the conversion.  Please file a bug at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues if this issue is important to you.